# Successively add columns to dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking to go through 20 iterations where I add 1 new column to an existing dataframe in each iteration.  The column will be a value from the random uniform distribution between 1 and 100.  My actual dataframes are 10000 rows, but the format of the dataframes is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(319, 77, 222, 107, 167),
                  var2 = c(137, 290, 237, 52, 192),
                  class = c(1,1,0,1,0))
```

Ideally, the columns added will be named var3, var4,...., var21 with each iteration.  I need to fit some models after each iteration as each individual column is added to the dataframe, in order to show how their accuracy declines as more columns are added of information that is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have var1 and var2, you could iterate through 3 to 20 with a for loop:

```
for (i in 3:20) {
  col_name <- paste0("var", i)
  df[[col_name]] <- runif(5, 0, 100) #5 because df has 5 rows
}
```

This will create vars3, var4, ...var 20.

Comment: its 20 new variables on top of the 2 existing, and I have to keep the class variable in the dataframe.  So the loop will have to start at 4, essentially to add onto the dataframe starting at column 4.  But this fundamentally will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(319, 77, 222, 107, 167),
                  var2 = c(137, 290, 237, 52, 192),
                  class = c(1,1,0,1,0))
for(i in 1:20){
col = paste('var_new_',i)
df[col] = runif(5)
# Add model code here
}
df
```

Comment: If I loop through starting at 1, will this write over the columns already existing in df, or add them on after the class variable??

Comment: It will overwrite.